# Can I have multiple Schema markups on the same webpage?

Tags: seo, schema.org, json-ld

I make articles on specific ingredients and provide their nutrition facts.

On my article page, I have this current schema for the `Article` type which works perfectly fine from what I know. But I'd like to have another schema that includes the nutrition label on the webpage.

If I can add another schema to the code:

- Can it be in the same `script` tag?
- Which one should be used?

```html
<!-- JSON-LD markup generated by Google Structured Data Markup Helper. -->
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "Article",
    "mainEntityOfPage": {
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "@id": "http://cathscafe.example.com/"
  },
  "name" : "Olive Oil Review - 2019",
  "headline" : "Olive Oil Review",
  "author" : {
    "@type" : "Person",
    "name" : "Christopher Karam"
  },
  "datePublished" : "2019-01-04",
  "dateModified" : "2019-01-04",
  "image" : "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/59a7820e2994ca11766093d3/t/5b00a06f575d1f8e6e07c981/1526767728080/olive-oil-fat-healthy-food-dietary-my-diet-goal-small-hd.jpg",
  "articleSection" : "Wellness",
  "articleBody" : "Olive oil is a liquid fat obtained from olives, a traditional tree crop of the Mediterranean. The oil is produced by cold pressing whole olives...",
  "url" : "https://mydietgoal.com/olive-oil",
  "publisher" : {
    "@type" : "Organization",
    "name" : "MyDietGoal",
    "logo" : { 
    "@type": "ImageObject",
    "name": "MyDietGoalLogo",
   "url" : "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/59a7820e2994ca11766093d3/t/5b6f96c6032be42d1403dd79/1551652043684.jpg",
    "width" : "250",
    "height" : "250"
  }},
  "aggregateRating" : {
    "@type" : "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue" : "5.0",
    "bestRating" : "5.0",
    "ratingCount" : "6"
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: [Cross-posted to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54990793/1591669)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**According to schema.org *NutritionInformation* is** [**only applicable to menu items or recipes**](https://schema.org/NutritionInformation#incoming). If you are trying to markup something else you would need to emulate this with all of the required fields.

Putting another object in the same `<script>` tag would technically be correct, you need to use a [JSON array[]](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp), though.
Neither [Google's validator](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) nor [Yandex' validator](https://webmaster.yandex.com/tools/microtest/) will return any warnings or errors for such a snippet:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
[
  {
    "@context" : "http://schema.org",
    "@type" : "Article",
      "mainEntityOfPage": {
      "@type": "WebPage",
      "@id": "http://cathscafe.example.com/"
    },
    "name" : "Olive Oil Review - 2019",
    "headline" : "Olive Oil Review",
    "author" : {
      "@type" : "Person",
      "name" : "Christopher Karam"
    },
    "datePublished" : "2019-01-04",
    "dateModified" : "2019-01-04",
    "image" : "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/59a7820e2994ca11766093d3/t/5b00a06f575d1f8e6e07c981/1526767728080/olive-oil-fat-healthy-food-dietary-my-diet-goal-small-hd.jpg",
    "articleSection" : "Wellness",
    "articleBody" : "Olive oil is a liquid fat obtained from olives, a traditional tree crop of the Mediterranean. The oil is produced by cold pressing whole olives...",
    "url" : "https://mydietgoal.com/olive-oil",
    "publisher" : {
      "@type" : "Organization",
      "name" : "MyDietGoal",
      "logo" : { 
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "name": "MyDietGoalLogo",
     "url" : "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/59a7820e2994ca11766093d3/t/5b6f96c6032be42d1403dd79/1551652043684.jpg",
      "width" : "250",
      "height" : "250"
    }},
    "aggregateRating" : {
      "@type" : "AggregateRating",
      "ratingValue" : "5.0",
      "bestRating" : "5.0",
      "ratingCount" : "6"
    }
  },
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Recipe",
    "author": "John Smith",
    "cookTime": "PT1H",
    "datePublished": "2009-05-08",
    "description": "This classic banana bread recipe comes from my mom -- the walnuts add a nice texture and flavor to the banana bread.",
    "image": "bananabread.jpg",
    "recipeIngredient": [
      "3 or 4 ripe bananas, smashed",
      "1 egg",
      "3/4 cup of sugar"
    ],
    "interactionStatistic": {
      "@type": "InteractionCounter",
      "interactionType": "http://schema.org/Comment",
      "userInteractionCount": "140"
    },
    "name": "Mom's World Famous Banana Bread",
    "nutrition": {
      "@type": "NutritionInformation",
      "calories": "240 calories",
      "fatContent": "9 grams fat"
    },
    "prepTime": "PT15M",
    "recipeInstructions": "Preheat the oven to 350 degrees. Mix in the ingredients in a bowl. Add the flour last. Pour the mixture into a loaf pan and bake for one hour.",
    "recipeYield": "1 loaf",
    "suitableForDiet": "http://schema.org/LowFatDiet"
  }
]
</script>
```

If you wish you can put both of them in separate `<script>` tags, and the result will be the same:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "Article",
    "mainEntityOfPage": {
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "@id": "http://cathscafe.example.com/"
  },
  "name" : "Olive Oil Review - 2019",
  "headline" : "Olive Oil Review",
  "author" : {
    "@type" : "Person",
    "name" : "Christopher Karam"
  },
  "datePublished" : "2019-01-04",
  "dateModified" : "2019-01-04",
  "image" : "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/59a7820e2994ca11766093d3/t/5b00a06f575d1f8e6e07c981/1526767728080/olive-oil-fat-healthy-food-dietary-my-diet-goal-small-hd.jpg",
  "articleSection" : "Wellness",
  "articleBody" : "Olive oil is a liquid fat obtained from olives, a traditional tree crop of the Mediterranean. The oil is produced by cold pressing whole olives...",
  "url" : "https://mydietgoal.com/olive-oil",
  "publisher" : {
    "@type" : "Organization",
    "name" : "MyDietGoal",
    "logo" : { 
    "@type": "ImageObject",
    "name": "MyDietGoalLogo",
   "url" : "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/59a7820e2994ca11766093d3/t/5b6f96c6032be42d1403dd79/1551652043684.jpg",
    "width" : "250",
    "height" : "250"
  }},
  "aggregateRating" : {
    "@type" : "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue" : "5.0",
    "bestRating" : "5.0",
    "ratingCount" : "6"
  }
}
</script>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Recipe",
  "author": "John Smith",
  "cookTime": "PT1H",
  "datePublished": "2009-05-08",
  "description": "This classic banana bread recipe comes from my mom -- the walnuts add a nice texture and flavor to the banana bread.",
  "image": "bananabread.jpg",
  "recipeIngredient": [
    "3 or 4 ripe bananas, smashed",
    "1 egg",
    "3/4 cup of sugar"
  ],
  "interactionStatistic": {
    "@type": "InteractionCounter",
    "interactionType": "http://schema.org/Comment",
    "userInteractionCount": "140"
  },
  "name": "Mom's World Famous Banana Bread",
  "nutrition": {
    "@type": "NutritionInformation",
    "calories": "240 calories",
    "fatContent": "9 grams fat"
  },
  "prepTime": "PT15M",
  "recipeInstructions": "Preheat the oven to 350 degrees. Mix in the ingredients in a bowl. Add the flour last. Pour the mixture into a loaf pan and bake for one hour.",
  "recipeYield": "1 loaf",
  "suitableForDiet": "http://schema.org/LowFatDiet"
}
</script>
```

You can find more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723531/best-json-ld-practices-using-multiple-script-elements#answer-32954313).

Comment: Do "Detected Warnings" have any impact on the results from Googles' end?

Comment: @ChristopherKaram if you're referring to the warnings for the above snippet it's more of a suggestion - I suppose the impact could be that somebody implementing more information than you could benefit. In general, you should always follow the spec unless you have a very good reason not to.